# Update first value from multiple result join SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have this query

```
UPDATE CCR_ARIZTIA 
SET HORA_ENTRADA_CLI = D1
FROM 
    CCR_ARIZTIA C
LEFT JOIN 
    TEMP_ALM_V_TEMP T ON ID_POLIGONO = POLIGONO AND T.L2 = C.L2
                       AND D1 > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) AND D1 < GETDATE() 
WHERE 
    FECHA_PEDIDO = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) 
    AND HORA_ENTRADA_CLI IS NULL 
    AND I4 = 222
```

It works fine, except when exists more than a D1 value that matches the join conditions. In this case the update sets the last value.

How can I prevent this? I want that the value of D1 be the first to appear.

I tried to use group by and order desc, but it seems that you can not use them in update statements.

Thank you.

**EDIT**:

When I run this query I have the the following results.

```
SELECT ID_CCR, MIN(D1) AS D1

FROM CCR_ARIZTIA C

LEFT JOIN TEMP_ALM_V_TEMP T ON ID_POLIGONO = POLIGONO AND T.L2 = C.L2
AND D1 > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) AND D1 < GETDATE() 

WHERE FECHA_PEDIDO = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) AND HORA_ENTRADA_CLI IS NULL AND I4 = 222

GROUP BY ID_CCR

ID_CCR  D1
4088    2014-11-17 09:21:19.000
4090    2014-11-17 07:20:16.000
4105    2014-11-17 13:23:00.000
4194    2014-11-17 12:53:52.000
```

This are the values I want to update in HORA_ENTRADA_CLI

Comment: When you say you want the value which one do you want? Keep in mind that tables have no order. When you want the "first" value, you have to define what the order is so you know what the first value is.

Comment: Realy I want the min() value, in this case is the first inserted in the TEMP_ALM_V_TEMP because is the insertion date.

Comment: Then just use MIN(D1). I will post an answer so you can see how this works.

Comment: I tried to put `UPDATE CCR_ARIZTIA SET HORA_ENTRADA_CLI = min(D1)` but it gave me this error "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement". I really appreciate an example

Comment: fwiw, Sql Server 2000 is end of life: it's no longer supported by Microsoft, and no longer receives any updates: _not even critical security updates._ It's irresponsible to continue using this product, and convincing management to upgrade is job #1 here.

Comment: Which is the PK of table CCR_ARIZTIA?

Comment: Have you deleted your response? It works adding `WHERE C.ID_CCR = CCR_ARIZTIA.ID_CCR`. I wanted to put your answer as acepted.

Comment: Have a look at my newly edited answer. I hope it is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the job you want in Sql Server 2000:

```
UPDATE CCR_ARIZTIA 
SET HORA_ENTRADA_CLI = C.D1
FROM (SELECT ID_CCR, MIN(D1) AS D1
      FROM CCR_ARIZTIA C
      LEFT JOIN TEMP_ALM_V_TEMP T ON ID_POLIGONO = POLIGONO AND T.L2 = C.L2
                                      AND D1 > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) AND D1 < GETDATE() 
      WHERE FECHA_PEDIDO = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) AND HORA_ENTRADA_CLI IS NULL AND I4 = 222      
      GROUP BY ID_CCR) C
WHERE C.ID_CCR = CCR_ARIZTIA.ID_CCR
```

Comment: I have this error: `[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@CCR_ARIZTIA'.
42000 - [SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@CCR_ARIZTIA'.`

Comment: I accidentaly posted an answer with @ because I used table variables to test the syntax of my query. Just remove all @s. See the edited answer above.

Comment: The query runs, but it says `Affected rows: 0`. I'm going to edit the question to add information.

Comment: Just add some sample data that display the problem you have. Also try to simplify the structure of the tables involved.

Comment: I have completely revised the query based on the edit you made. Hope it works this time!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a cte.

Since I don't have ddl to work with I have to guess a little bit. You will need to change PrimaryKey to whatever makes sense to use a grouping column(s).

```
with MyUpdate as
(
    Select HORA_ENTRADA_CLI
        , MIN(D1)
    FROM CCR_ARIZTIA C
    LEFT JOIN TEMP_ALM_V_TEMP T ON ID_POLIGONO = POLIGONO 
        AND T.L2 = C.L2 AND D1 > cast(GETDATE() as DATE) 
        AND D1 < GETDATE() 
    WHERE FECHA_PEDIDO = cast(GETDATE() as DATE)
        AND HORA_ENTRADA_CLI IS NULL 
        AND I4 = 222
    group by [PrimaryKey]
)


UPDATE MyUpdate
SET HORA_ENTRADA_CLI = D1
```

Comment: @Sean I think the OP wants sth that runs in sql server 2000. CTE are available from 2005 (?)

Comment: This code is for using as is? The query gave me this error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'`

Comment: UGH!!! I just assumed you weren't still using sql 2000. This won't work in there. I would recommend upgrading if you have even half a chance.

Comment: I really like it, but the server belongs to a company for which I work

Comment: @DanielGarcía You really should encourage them to upgrade. SQL Server 2000 has been end-of-lifed and out of support for quite some time now, which means no patches even for security issues. http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=sql